# Мини логика игры Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть `10` кнопок. Также есть метод `PlayNumber(int i)`, который цепляется на `OnClick` с индексом `i`, который, в свою очередь, при нажатии на кнопку с этим индексом, выводит ее в текст. Т.е. нажали на кнопку `1` - в текст поместился `1`.

```
    public void PlayNumber(int i)
    {
        int number = i+1;
        rand = Random.Range (0, 8);
        DisplayText.enabled = false;
        Displaynumber = Displaynumber + number;
        DisplayNumber.text = Displaynumber.ToString ();
        if (Displaynumber.ToString ().Length == 3) 
        {
                animals [rand].SetActive (true);
                Displaynumber = null;
                anim.Play ();
        } 
        else    
            anim.Stop();
   }
```

Далее, есть метод в другом классе `CheckCountNumber`, который тоже цепляется на эти кнопки. По условию случайным образом игроку предлагается нажать кнопку, допустим, `2`, если игрок нажимает не `2`, а, допустим, другую цифру, `7`, тогда не записывать в дисплей эту цифру, записывать только в том случае, если нажатая кнопка `tempIteratorNumber`  была равна случайному числу `rand`.

Т.е., примитивно, есть игра, где просто нажимать кнопки `1` `2` `6`, и эти цифры отображаются в тексте, есть вторая игра на основе этой, которая говорит: нажми (рандомные числа от `0` до `9`) если игрок нажимает на ту, которая говорилась, тогда записывать в текст, если говорили нажать `5`, а он нажал все кроме `5`, не записывать в текст:

```
public void CheckCountNumber()
    {
            if (tempIteratorNumber == rand) // Нажали правильно
            {
                if (countWinsNumber == 3) 
                    {
                        EffectWin.PlayEffect ();
                    }
            } 
            else
            {       
                _phone.ClearPawButton ();
            }
            rand  = Random.Range (0,9);
            StartNumberGame (rand);
    }
```

Помогите разобраться, я запутался и в безысходности)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так, ну вот вам простейший вариант реализации описанной вами механики:
Наполнение двух методов можно изменять на свой вкус, как и отображение итога.

```
[SerializeField]
Text _tableText;

int _curentNum;

public void OnButtonClick(int number)
{
    if (number == _curentNum)
    {
      Win();
    } 
    else
    {
      Fail();
    }
}

void Fail()
{
   Debug.Log("Haha! Fail!");
}

void Win()
{
   _tableText.text = number.ToString();
   NewIteration();
   Debug.Log("Haha! Win!");
}

void NewIteration()
{
    _curentNum = Random.Range (0,9);     
}
```